# How do I know what a character has seen?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Apparently, Roderick has spotted something:

[image: A good question]
*A good question*

However, I can't for the life of me figure out what it is!

Is there some way to highlight whatever it is he's discovered? Holding alt doesn't seem to do anything.

(This particular instance is behind the permanently closed General Store in Cyseal, but I'm sure it'll come up again later)

Comment: He is talking about the painting in there, but I really wouldn't know a way to see what he sees. I just randomly hover over stuff and check the room fully when he has said it.

Comment: Oh well that's silly, I'm not even in the house at this point. I guess he's just perceptive enough to see this through the window.

Answer (score 2):

So as it turns out, what's *supposed* to happen is that the newly discovered thing appears, with a shiny overlay. For some reason it wasn't happening in my previous position, but here's what it normally looks like:

[image: A strange rock formation!]
*A strange rock formation!*

[image: Secretly, it's a grave]
*Secretly, it was a grave!*

Comment: This does work, but in some cases the object is visually obstructed by another object (e.g. secret switch behind a picture on the wall) or very, very small (a key or button).